Open pdf files by terminal with fzf and fd
with the following command line, which I turned into an alias, I would like to open the pdf files from my terminal.

alias pdfLoad="fd . '$HOME/OneDrive/DBCalibre' -t f -e pdf  | fzf | xargs -0 -I {} masterpdfeditor5 {}"

However, I noticed a problem caused by particular characters such as ' which does not allow me to open the file.
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Kernel: 6.12.4-arch1-1 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
DE: GNOME 47.2
fzf 0.56.3 (add1aec6)
fd 10.2.0
masterpdfeditor5 Build 5.9.86, 64 bit


Please [edit] your question and show us the actual alias definition. Ideally, also mention your operating system (if you're using Arch, please don't tag with Arch, just mention it in the question; the Arch tag should only be used for questions asking specifically about how Arch works). Same for zsh, if that is the shel you are using, just mention it in the question, don't tag with it unless the question is specifically about zsh somehow.

I'm not familiar with fd nor fzf nor masterpdfeditor5 but I can at least tell that the xargs command won't work because you use the -0 for NUL‑delimited records while feeding LF-delimited ones to it...
An easy fix (and most probably the best one when dealing with paths) is to use NUL-delimited records in all the commands of the pipeline:
fd . ~/OneDrive/DBCalibre -t f -e pdf -0 |
fzf --read0 --print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 masterpdfeditor5

